# calculating profit with thresholds using sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to calculate profit generated from revenue by year. Below is example 5 years and the revenue generated:

```
 year    revenue
 1       5,000,000
 2       10,000,000
 3       25,000,000
 4       30,000,000
 5       30,000,000
```

The percentage to apply to calculate the profit is listed below and is dependant on the absolute revenue in the year. Essentially the % profit generated decreases as the revenue increases.

Table below represents the minimum revenue for the given percentage. For example: revenue up to 15m has a profit percentage of 30%, revenue between 15-20m > 28%, revenue between 20-25m > 25% and 25m+ > 20%.

```
 min_revenue     profit_perc
 0               0.3
 15,000,000      0.28
 20,000,000      0.25
 25,000,000      0.2
```

For example, in year 1 the calculation is simple as the revenue only falls into one bucket so its simply `5,000,000 * 0.3` to get to the profit.

The calculation gets more complicated in year 4 and 5 as the revenue falls into multiple buckets. Example calculation for year 4:

`15,000,000 * 0.3 + 5,000,000 * 0.28 + 5,000,000 * 0.25 + 5,000,000 * 0.2`

honestly dont know where to start with this one in sql, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I would suggest adding `max_revenue` to the revenue table.  In most databases, you could just use `lead()` to do this.

```
select year, revenue, sum(prof)
from (select year, revenue, min(e.revenue, r.max_revenue) * r.profit_perc as prof
      from example5 e join
           revenue r
           on e.revenue >= e.min_revenue
     ) yr
group by year, revenue;
```

If you cannot directly add it, then you can use a correlated subquery to get the next revenue.